# How I can check whether 2 databases haves same data and schema fast?

Tags: mariadb

A coleague of mine has does a mysqldump into the same db server.
I want to know when it is complete so I can use it.

Is there a way to compare 2 databases and check whether dump is complete. I assume dump is complete if both dbs have same structure and data.

Is there to check quickly if 2 databases on the same server are the same? I have both access to 2 databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a tool that can compare the two databases for you and show you the different objects and data, I've found the [SQL Examiner Suite](https://www.sqlaccessories.com/sql-examiner-suite/) to work really well over the years. It'll even generate the scripts and automatically synchronize the databases for you as needed. It can be called through batch processes and scheduled, as well as a few other features are included.

Unfortunately it's not free, but it's definitely worth its price tag and has made my job as a DBA measurably easier. Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with this tool or company in any way; I'm only a user of the tool for many years.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to discover when the mysqldump is finished.  Do that by looking in Task Manager or ps (or top or htop) to see if `mysqldump` is no longer in the list of running tasks.

To compare two databases, you must first load the dump.  This may take even longer than the dump.  So it seems like a clumsy way to "check for finished".